# Struggling to find a good Instrumental Variable for Housing Tenure (Social housing)

Tags: instrumental-variables, social-science

As part of some research, i am examining the impact of living in social housing on youth violence at a borough level (London). The explanatory variable (social housing) clearly exhibits endogeneity but I can't seem to find a relevant IV. I considered using Average Property price but I'm not sure if this satisfies the exogeneity condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some more contextual information?

Comment: I believe that the Social Housing variable exhibits selection and simultaneity bias and therefore need to counteract this with an instrumental variable. However, I am struggling to find a variable which satisfies both IV conditions (relevance and exogeneity). Any help on potential instruments that I could use would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance